# Select the current element jquery - multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I'm new with jquery and I'm trying to understand how can I hover the current element in my situation:

```
<div class="feat_pic">
  <div class="feat_bg_img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> );"><div class="layer"></div></div>
  <a class="home-feat-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
</div>

<div class="feat_pic">
  <div class="feat_bg_img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> );"><div class="layer"></div></div>
  <a class="home-feat-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
</div>

<div class="feat_pic">
  <div class="feat_bg_img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> );"><div class="layer"></div></div>
  <a class="home-feat-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
</div>
```

I know that I'm somewhat close to what I want to acomplish, here's the code:

```
$(".feat_pic").hover(function(){
        $(".home-featured ul li .feat_container ul li .feat_bg_img .layer").addClass("lilith");
        $(".home-featured ul li a.home-feat-title").addClass("satan");
    }, function(){
        $(".home-featured ul li .feat_container ul li .feat_bg_img .layer").removeClass("lilith");
        $(".home-featured ul li a.home-feat-title").removeClass("satan");
    });
```

How can I make that `add.Class` to work only on the current `.feat_pic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this` inside the event handler to refer to the hovered `feat_pic` element, then you can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the `.layer` and `.home-feat-title` element inside it like

```
$(".feat_pic").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".feat_bg_img .layer").addClass("lilith");
    $(this).find("a.home-feat-title").addClass("satan");
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".feat_bg_img .layer").removeClass("lilith");
    $(this).find("a.home-feat-title").removeClass("satan");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rxwL0hx5/)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this, but didn't worked for me.I used something like this: `$(this).find("".home-featured ul li .feat_container ul li .feat_bg_img .layer").addClass("lilith");` .Maybe because I used the full path, could that affect something?

Comment: @MarianIoan because `home-featured` is not a descendant of `feat_pic` element

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".feat_pic").hover(function(){
    var me = $(this); // current .feat_pic
    me.addClass('className');
    $(".home-featured ul li .feat_container ul li .feat_bg_img .layer").addClass("lilith");
    $(".home-featured ul li a.home-feat-title").addClass("satan");
}, function(){
    $(".home-featured ul li .feat_container ul li .feat_bg_img .layer").removeClass("lilith");
    $(".home-featured ul li a.home-feat-title").removeClass("satan");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "this" instead of specifying class name in your case

```
$(this).hover(function(){
    $(".home-featured ul li .feat_container ul li .feat_bg_img .layer").addClass("lilith");
    (".home-featured ul li a.home-feat-title").removeClass("satan");
});
```